# Backbone/Marionette Root Layout Errors with Webpack

Tags: webpack, marionette

I have a Backbone/Marionette app that I've been developing with RequireJS, and I'm working on converting it to Webpack. Webpack nicely packages up my code, but when I try to load the packaged JS, it's hitting an error where the layout's DOM is unable to find one of the core regions. The error message is "An "el" #content must exist in DOM".

A stubbed out version of my source follows:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/app/bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content" class="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var RootLayout = Marionette.View.extend({
    el: 'body',

    regions: {
        content: '#content'
    }
});

new RootLayout().getRegion('content').show(someView);
```

I'm working with Marionette v3.0.0-pre.3 currently, but haven't had any issues with it prior to switching to Webpack - it may or may not be relevant. Ideas on how I could resolve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I tried switching things up, and define the root app el in my Marionette.Application - I got the same error there. It makes me think that something is messed up with backbone's use of jquery. I'm having trouble debugging because every breakpoint comes up in handlebars.js for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one of the changes I made to my init.js file caused the issue somehow. I was using nested requires to load amd dependencies in the right order, and I switched the way it was working to change the chunks output. Reverting that change resolved the issue.

Edit: I've gone farther down the path of converting my app over - because it's running on a Node server I decided to convert all of my RequireJS module definitions over to CommonJS, and this issue reared its ugly head again. After several hours of bashing my head against a wall, I realized that the issue was my view was being attached to the DOM before the HTML element it lives on was actually loaded. A simple $(document).ready wrapper around my init code was the real solution (I actually just moved the script tag for my webpack bundle to the bottom of the HTML).

tl;dr - RequireJS insulates you from needing to make sure your DOM is ready before you start messing with it, while CommonJS doesn't. Async vs sync.